# Jbilling installation

Tags: java

> how to install jbilling-community-3.0.2 in windows system

please help me out.I will try all the possible way but it is not working.

Comment: This will help http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 1):

follow the instructions in the following tutorial: http://www.jbilling.com/documentation/users/installation/windows

it should be straightforward.

If you can't get it installed using this simple Tutorial above; then hire a professional JBilling developer to help you install it.

BTW: I can help you install it. contact me if you want and i'll assist you in your local system to get it installed.

Answer (score 1):

**Steps taken to set up jbilling-community-3.0.2.zip from binary:**

Download the binary zip.
Note: Requires Java6, configure it in a standard way according to your operating system, i.e. windows, linux, mac.

//Extract the zip contents
unzip -q jbilling-community-3.0.2.zip

cd jbilling-community-3.0.2/bin/

chmod +x *.sh

./startup.sh && tail -f ../logs/catalina.out

**Steps taken to set up jbilling-community-3.0.2-src.zip source zip:**

Download the zip.
Note:

1. Requires Java6, configure it in a standard way according to your operating system, i.e. windows, linux, mac.
2. Requires Postgres Version 8.x or higher installed on your local

//Extract the zip contents
unzip -q jbilling-community-3.0.2-src.zip

cd jbilling-community-3.0.2/

1. grails clean
2. grails compile
3. grails compile
4. dropdb -U jbilling jbilling_test
5. createdb -U jbilling jbilling_test
6. grails prepare-test --verbose
7. grails run-app

**Database Setup**

In order to use a different database, check *grails-app/conf/DataSource.groovy* file to setup the dataSource property for an alternate Database. By default, the extracted src zip of jBilling connects to *jbilling_test* using the user *jbilling*

Comment: Check https://github.com/WebDataConsulting/billing/wiki/Installing-jBilling-(from-Binary-and-or-Source)

Answer (score 0):

I was stumbled on the same issue to get it installed. But in my case, i had to remove catalina_home and path to tomcat installation in environment variables which was installed earlier. the jbilling zip file is shipped with tomcat server pre-installed and configured to function properly.

if the above is not your case. post the error stacktrace, so audience can understand what is going on.